# Remove all code chunks from R Markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Using `knitr::purl()`, it is easy to extract *all code chunks* from an R Markdown document, i.e.:

`knitr::purl("foo.Rmd")`

creates the file:

`foo.R`

However, what if I've done this, and am now interested in extracting just plain text (or removing all code chunks from an R Markdown document). Is there an (easy) way to do this?